# Need to apply two content view same time

Tags: android

I need to apply two content view same time. That mean i add an image in layout. Then need to plot some dots on a canvas. so here is the code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    canvas cs = new canvas(this);
    setContentView(cs);
    setContentView(R.layout.car_kdu);

}
```

If someone can please help me.i got only one content at a time. But i need both..

Comment: You can't set two views simultaneously, doesnt make sense. If you want them to overlap then use a frame layout

Comment: you can have a viewgroup in your xml and add canvas to the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible. Both ImageView and the Canvas will need to be in a single layout that you set using [setContentView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView%28android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29).

Your layout will need to be something like.

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" />
    <com.my.Canvas android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

That will create a layout with both views sharing the space 50%.